# Can't look at Microsoft.DocumentDB usage quota

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When I go to `Usage + quotas` in my azure account I can't chose the `Microsoft.DocumentDB` provider. How do I look at the `Microsoft.DocumentDB` provider usage quota?

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB does not expose quota and service limits through that page.

Visit, [Azure Cosmos DB service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits) to get the list. All increases are handled by [raising a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/create-support-request-quota-increase).

Comment: I don't understand, why would my currently configured usage quota be in the documentation?

Comment: I need to know my current quota, because the ticket template for an increase asks for it. It's part of `4. Details` which the documentation skips and doesn't elaborate on

Comment: Quota for what?

Comment: Quota for Cosmos Databases

Comment: It's in that article. 500 databases (or containers) per Cosmos DB account.

Comment: I think it fails for me when creating the Cosmos DB account. Something about high demand (in all regions I've tried it in) and needing to apply for a quota through support

Comment: Yes. That's a capacity issue. Is not related to service quota or limits. If you receive that error message, please follow it's instructions and open a ticket. Thanks.